# Determine size of a table or selected records in terms of bytes/megabytes

Tags: postgresql, size, byte, diskspace

I've been a bit lazy lately and have been generating gigabytes of PostGis database records much of which I don't need anymore. I'm beginning to think of cleaning it out a bit, but want to determine how many bytes these records are taking up.

I'm using rails, so if I could call a method or SQL snippet on an already selected group of records to determine the size of said records in bytes this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the table:

```
SELECT  pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('name_of_tbl'));
```

For a particular table row and/or column in it:

```
SELECT pg_column_size(t) AS row_size_on_disk
       pg_column_size(t.column1) AS column1_size_on_disk
FROM   tbl t
WHERE  tbl_id = ?;
```

See:

- [Measure the size of a PostgreSQL table row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/23933/3684)
- [What is the overhead for varchar(n)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/125526/3684)

Comment: Not that it's that important, but you can also add  pg_size_pretty() around either of the functions above to get "pretty" sizes instead of bytes.

Comment: I marked this as correct a while back but am just now trying it out and am getting the following: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "horry_parcels" does not exist` after running this command: `SELECT pg_total_relation_size(horry_parcels)`. Does pg_total_relation_size take table names or not? It sounds like its expecting a column name. 'Could be rails doing something funky. This is the full command: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "SELECT pg_total_relation_size(horry_parcels)"`

Comment: @boulder_ruby: When inserting a table name directly you have to use single quotes for the string literal: `SELECT pg_total_relation_size('horry_parcels')` I clarified my answer. Refer to the linked answer on dba.SE for more.